# Spring Batch combined with Atomikos not working

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jta, atomikos, transactionmanager

I’m having trouble configuring an Tomcat – Spring Batch – Atomikos combination.
I have configured the following (I’m not mentioning the JMS configuration)

- Atomikos DataSource (proxy) based on 
  com.atomikos.tomcat.EnhancedTomcatAtomikosBeanFactory for Oracle XA datasource.
- JtaTransactionManager based on 
  transactionManager based on com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeTransactionManager
  userTransaction based on
  com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction

When executing a batch job I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Transaction Service Not Running?
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction.checkSetup(J2eeUserTransaction.java:70)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction.getStatus(J2eeUserTransaction.java:125)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.
        isExistingTransaction(JtaTransactionManager.java:797)
```

**Debugging revealed  the following:**

Spring Batch makes use of TaskletStep. This class uses a PlatformTransactionManager that is instantiated with a DataSourceTransactionManager? The datasource is referring to a AtomikosDataSourceBean, that seems ok.
I have several questions:

- Where is this DataSourceTransactionManager coming from? I have defined a JtaTransactionManager!
- I thought the AtomikosDataSourceBean acts like a proxy to connect to JtaTransactionManager. Why is Atomikos given the error “Transaction Service Not Running?”

Spring Batch: 2.1.8

Atomikos:     3.9.3